# problems accents in email magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have a magento website running version 1.8.1.0
I wanted to edit the email templates that are sent when a customer order something. Everything goes fine, till I put some letters with accents like éèà.  The mails aren't sent anymore.

Can someone tell me how I can change that?

Comment: This question belongs on http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

Try to use html codes like `&eacute;` (é) `&egrave;` (è) and `&agrave;` (à).

You can find an overview of html codes on: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: yes that works, but it is not very easy to write a text like that. Is there somewhere a converter to do that?

Comment: I don't think this is a viable solution to the problem since the accented character could be in the address lines, city or the name of the customer that ordered something on the website. There should be a better solution to this.